# How to select multiple items in treewidget and delete those items?

Tags: linux, qt, qtreewidget

When I am selecting items in treewidget and then clicked on delete button then is is just deleting top most item only from treewidget 
Can you correct this code? 
This function is calling in connect statement while clicking on button

```
void TableDockWidget::deleteGroup() {

QTreeWidgetItem *item = treeWidget->currentItem();

QTreeWidgetItem* nextItem = treeWidget->itemBelow(item);

if ( item == NULL ) return;

PeakGroup* group = getSelectedGroup(); //this function is using to                        //select items from treewidget

if ( group == NULL ) return;

PeakGroup* parentGroup = group->parent;

if ( parentGroup == NULL ) { //top level item

    deleteGroup(group); //this is using to delete group
} else if ( parentGroup && parentGroup->childCount() ) {    //this a child item
    if ( parentGroup->deleteChild(group) ) {
        QTreeWidgetItem* parentItem = item->parent();
        if ( parentItem ) {
            parentItem->removeChild(item);
            delete(item);
        }
    }
}
//show NextItem
if(nextItem) treeWidget->setCurrentItem(nextItem,0);
return;
```

}

//here, code of function which is selecting items.

```
PeakGroup* TableDockWidget::getSelectedGroup() { 
QTreeWidgetItem *item = treeWidget->currentItem();
if (!item) return NULL;
QVariant v = item->data(0,Qt::UserRole);
PeakGroup*  group =  v.value<PeakGroup*>();
if ( group != NULL ) { return group; }
return NULL;
```

}

// code of function which is deleting group

```
void TableDockWidget::deleteGroup(PeakGroup *groupX) {
qDebug() << "TableDockWidget::deleteGroup()";
if(!groupX) return;

int pos=-1;
for(int i=0; i < allgroups.size(); i++) {
    if ( &allgroups[i] == groupX ) {
        pos=i; break;
    }
}
if (pos == -1) return;

//qDebug() << "Delete pos=" << pos;
QTreeWidgetItemIterator it(treeWidget);
while (*it) {
    QTreeWidgetItem* item = (*it);
    if (item->isHidden()) { ++it; continue; }
    QVariant v = item->data(0,Qt::UserRole);
    PeakGroup*  group =  v.value<PeakGroup*>();
    if ( group != NULL and group == groupX) {
        item->setHidden(true);

        //Deleteing
        allgroups.erase(allgroups.begin()+pos);
        int posTree = treeWidget->indexOfTopLevelItem(item);
        if (posTree != -1) treeWidget->takeTopLevelItem(posTree);
        break;
    }
    ++it;
}

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < allgroups.size(); i++) {
    allgroups[i].groupId = i + 1;
}
updateTable();
_mainwindow->getEicWidget()->replotForced();
```

}

Comment: I fixed my problem.

Comment: Please post the answer for people to see. It can help future people that will come with a similar problem.

Comment: I meant to post it as an answer for this topic, and show it as "Solved" once the cooldown for self-solving is over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PeakGroup* TableDockWidget::getSelectedGroup() { 
PeakGroup*  group;
QList<QTreeWidgetItem*>selected = treeWidget->selectedItems();
if(selected.size() == 0) return NULL;
Q_FOREACH (QTreeWidgetItem* item, selected) {
          QVariant v = item->data(0,Qt::UserRole);
           group =  v.value<PeakGroup*>();
          item->setHidden(true);
       }
if ( group != NULL ) { return group; }
else
return NULL;
}
```